# How is loopback's ACL table used?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

When building a loopback application, it's clear that I can specify ACLs in the model definition (`model.json`), but I can't find any case where the actual `ACL` database table is actually populated or used. If a table created, then is it intended to be used by the framework, or is it simply a place to store ACLs that I would fill/apply myself?

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a Table/Collection named `ACL` to store ACLs, you provide for your Loopback application.

Now it is only to store the `ACLs` created at runtime i.e. defined in *js files* like `model.js`. The runtime `ACLs` can be created:

1. While defining a model using *Datasource's* `createModel()` or
2. Using *ACL's* `create()`.

Now since it is table/collection so you can add your `ACLs` manually as long as the incoming data is right. But prefer adding them in your `model.json`, second best your `model.js`.

You can read more about runtime `ACLs` [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB1/Advanced+topics).

Comment: I don't get this at all, why would you define your roles at runtime?  They'd all be gone when your app closes, right?  I must be missing something here.

Comment: I think @Vishal meant, if you created ACLs in a bootscript like here - https://gist.github.com/spencermefford/bc73812f216e0e254ad1. The rows are created in the table, so they will persist after your app/server terminates.